# What is the truth value of statements that talk about something that does not exist?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Consider the following statement:

> The king of France is bald.

We know that France does not currently have a king, so what is the truth value of this statement? If it is true, then its negation must be false, so the king of France is **not** bald is false, But when France does not have a king, does it make sense to determine the truth and falsity of this statement? What should be done with these types of statements?

Comment: There is a branch of logic called "temporal logic" which handles such propositions.

Comment: See [Russell's analysis of "denoting phrases"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Denoting). The issue involves quantifiers: thus, it is not propositional logic.

Comment: Free logic is the area of logic that is designed to handle terms that are nondenoting. There are many variations: some free logics require all atomic sentences containing nondenoting terms (like `the king of France') to be false; some free logics allow some such sentences to be true; and some require most of them to have no truth value. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I like the specification in that article: "there was no king of France at the time of Russell's article". Some times Wikipedia takes it a step further than may be necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Insofar as this is not just a question about linguistics, the way this sort of issue is handled in mathematics is that to even use the word "the" to refer to a mathematical object is to make an implicit claim that that object both exists and is unique, e.g. when we speak of "*the* cyclic group of order $n$" and so forth. So there is an implicit existential quantifier there (one might render it more explicitly as "there exists a unique person who is king of France, and..."), and if the domain of discourse over which that quantifier ranges is empty (in this case, if France does not have a king) then the statement is false.

One needs to be a bit careful about this in mathematics, though, because sometimes the implicit quantifier is a universal quantifier and then if the domain of discourse being quantified over is empty such statements are [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: So can it be said that the statement "The king of France is bald." is vacuously true?

Comment: @Amin: no, it's false. Take a look at my edit though. "*Every* king of France is bald" would be vacuously true.

Comment: I prefer to think that "the king of France is bald" is malformed, in the same way that a compiler would complain about undeclared or uninitialised variables.

Comment: I was able to prove that if $x$ is the only king of France, then x $is$ bald. Do you have a problem with that? (See my answer)

Answer (score -3):

(Updated screenshot from proof checker)

[image]
[image]